# CSS positioning for left nav

Tags: html, css, position

I'm trying to recreate a website and position the icons in a certain way. Currently I have a black nav bar on the left with icons. I want the black nav bar to extend all the way to bottom of the page and I also want the icons to be separated.

Here is the CSS code:

```
#left_nav {
border: solid black;
}

#left_nav i {
color: gray;
padding-right: 35%;
padding-left: 35%;
margin-top: 60%;
}
```

HTML code:

```
        <div id="left_nav" class="grid_2 alpha">
            <i class="ss-icon">home</i>
            <i class="ss-icon">time</i>
            <i class="ss-icon">user</i>
            <i class="ss-icon">question</i>
            <i class="ss-icon">play</i>
        </div>
```

Comment: I made a fiddle with the code you included.  I'm going to bet it doesn't illustrate your current situation. http://jsfiddle.net/5JK8S/

Comment: Yes it does represent it quite well. I just want the nav bar to extend to the bottom of the page and separate the icons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/3L5YV/

A few things:

- Inline elements (i.e. `<i>`) cannot have a margin. You'll have to make the element a block level element via `display:block;`
- In order for the sidebar to reach the whole page, you can set its height to 100%, but only after setting the height of its parent (in this case, the BODY and concurrently HTML elements) to 100% height.

CSS:

```
html, body{
    height: 100%; // height declared so child #left_nav can expand to this height
}
#left_nav { 
    border: solid black;
    height: 100%; // will expand to height of parent
}

#left_nav i {
    display:block; // added display:block; to allow for margin
    color: gray;
    padding-right: 35%;
    padding-left: 35%;
    margin: 10px 0; // only available to block level elements
}
```

Comment: Can you show me how to write the code for the inline elements?

Comment: Everything I mentioned is in that Fiddle. I'll update my answer to show you what I added.

Comment: So you can only add margin to block level elements, hence why we needed to change the display to display:block?

Comment: Also, what if I wanted the last icon to be further down than the rest?

Comment: Changing the `display` gives the element block-level attributes; aka the ability to adjust margin. If you wanted the last icon to be further down than the rest, you could add a class of `last` to the `<i>` element or make use of [CSS3's `:last-child` selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp) to apply a larger `margin`.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the :last-child selector?